# Why do my curtains get rendered with black triangles?

Tags: rendering, cloth-simulation, shape-keys

Doing my school work and my curtains get rendered like this. I wanted to apply the cloth modifier but it says I cant apply modifier to a mesh with shape keys

[image: the rendered curtains]

[image: the curtains in layout]

here is a file with the curtains (im using version 4.0):
[image]

Comment: Just to be clear : it's fine in the viewport, but all tangled in renders ?

Comment: @Hadriscus yeah, it looks fine in viewport but when i render it it looks like that

Comment: Once you're glad with the shape, remove the shapekeys, then apply the Cloth modifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't add to comment I don't have 50 reputation.
If you don't mind, can you share your file or curtain with us?

[image]

Left side your curtain with animation.
Right side Applied animation.

The problem is vertex order changes when you make an animation:
Transfer the vertex order! addon
https://app.gumroad.com/d/0065f9470cd9f631b7b079566831ba5c

Solution is explained;
Fix your SHAPE KEYS!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTgSLYY9uew

But if you want just curtain in keyframes Follow the image.

1.)Choose the simulation keyframe (Before you have to allow simulation play or bake the simulation process.)

2.)Select your animation object or objects. (one of them must be active select with LeftMouseButton)

3.)Object

4.)Apply

5.)Visual Geometry to Mesh

[image]

Then you have to Clean your mesh.

6.)Go to Constraints in Properties >> Apply or remove from mesh. (Be carefull you have 2 different objects means you have to make this process for 2 of them.)

7.)When you finished the work remove the Vertex Groups.

[image]

Comment: yes, i have added the file now

Comment: thank u very much. i dont know what i would do without u for real